# difference in behaviour between spring PropertyPlaceholderconfigurer and PropertyOverrideConfigurer

Tags: spring

I wanted to externalize my configuration properties so planned to use - PropertyPlaceholderconfigurer - here is my context file:

```
<bean id="helloBean" class="com.springex1.HelloWorld">
    <property name="name" value="test!{my.db.jdbc.driver}" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" id="testPropertyConfigurer">
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE"/>
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
    <property name="location" value="classpath:/springdb.properties"/>
    <property name="placeholderPrefix" value="test!{"/>
    <property name="placeholderSuffix" value="}"/>
    <property name="order" value="0"/>
</bean>
```

Simple java class - HelloWorld.java

```
public class HelloWorld {
private String name;

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void printHello() {
    System.out.println("Hello ! " + name);
}
```

My properties file:

```
my.db.jdbc.driver=xyz
foo=bar
```

All of this works fine. Note that the first property is being injected

> my.db.jdbc.driver=xyz

while the second property

> foo=bar

is not being used - but spring works fine and does not complain

Now I decided to override the properties - so decided to add the propertyOverrideConfigurer

```
<bean id="propertyOverrideConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyOverrideConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:/override.properties" />
    <property name="order" value="20" />
</bean>
```

Added the override.properties:

> helloBean.name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

This works as expected and prints - oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

Now my understanding was that I wanted to override the additional property

> foo=baz

And then code failed :

> Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not process key 'foo' in PropertyOverrideConfigurer; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Invalid key 'foo': expected 'beanName.property'

This part is understood - spring is looking for bean name 'helloBean' and then its corresponding attribute.

While the issue is understood - my question is - in PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer I can define additional properties which are not injected and it works fine.
But - PropertyOverrideConfigurer - any property defined must get injected and for that to happen - there must be a bean with attributes available

I cannot really have additional properties hanging around in case of PropertyOverrideConfigurer - which does not sound right.

am I missing something that can ignore this error ?